# Can systemd restart a service when a specific binary on the server is updated?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, systemd

On Ubuntu 18.04 I have Unattended Upgrades update apps regularly including a 3rd party PPA that installs a binary `/usr/bin/some_app`. My systemd unit file runs that service via `ExecStart=/usr/bin/some_app`. I can verify the updates work on schedule in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

However even when the binary is updated via Unattended Upgrades systemd doesn't restart the app, I assume because `some_app` is started via a custom unit file unrelated to that PPA. So from the cli `some_app --version` shows `v2.0.0` but systemd is still running `v1.0.0`.

Does systemd have a method to track a file or detect the binary referenced in `ExecStart` has changed on disk and it should restart? A backup hack for me would be using `RuntimeMaxSec=` which would get the job done, but I was hoping something more elegant existed

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a `.path` unit (man systemd.path) to watch for a `close()` after `write()` change to the file, which then restarts your app service. Not tested:

/etc/systemd/system/myappwatch.path

```
[Unit]
Description=watch for changed file
[Path]
PathChanged=/usr/bin/some_app
#Unit=myappwatch.service
```

/etc/systemd/system/myappwatch.service

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart myapp.service
```

You might be able to replace the `systemctl restart` with something magic like `Conflicts=myapp` but I'll let you experiment. You also need to enable the `.path` unit as usual with an appropriate `WantedBy=`. I'm not sure what happens if the path is a symbolic link, so perhaps you should resolve the path to the real file is that is the case.